# After importing my python googlemaps module it says unresolved attributes for .geocode and .reverse_geocode

Tags: python

in:

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='Add Your Key here')

# Geocoding an address
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')

# Look up an address with reverse geocoding
reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((40.714224, -73.961452))
```

Pycharm says that `.geocode` and `.reverse_geocode` are unresolved attributes...
Without them I can't use the API.
It's the official API from google: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

Comment: Is this YOUR googlemaps module? Tell us where it is hosted. The problem may lie with your project structure.

Comment: Are there any of your scripts called googlemaps.py?

Comment: My scripts are named main.py and test.py

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with Google billing, they want you to register a credit card and that fixed it.